# Changing default range for x- and y-axis in ListPlot3D

Tags: graphics

How do I change the default values for the x- and y- axis in this example without altering the z-axis values? For instance, I want the x-axis to follow a range based
on "x= 0.01 i+3" (not just i) , and y axis to range from -10 to 10 (instead of the default 0 to 20 shown on the plot below)?

```
ListPlot3D[Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, 10, 1}, {j, -10, 10, 1}], 
 Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
 ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ListPlot3D[Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, 10, 1}, {j, -10, 10, 1}], 
 Mesh -> None, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
 ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors", 
 DataRange -> {{0, .01 10 + 3}, {-10, 10}, Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]